# Predicting future values in a multivariate time forecasting LSTM model that predict future 10 days price on the basis of previous data

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am confused on how to predict future results with a time series multivariate LSTM model.

I am trying to build a model for a stock market prediction and I have the following data features

Date High Low Close Volume

If I train my model on 5 years of data up until today and I want to predict next 2 month High price essentially I will need to predict all the data features for tomorrow. This is where I am confused.... Because if all the data features are dependent on one another how do I predict  the future when all the data features for future are still unknown? Does anyone have any example code on how to deal with this issue?

I have to tried many function but I failed to create the function plz help me someone to create the function that will predict the future price based on previous input data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: encoder-decoder RNN?

Answer (score 0):

@Hamzakhan Swati!
What you are trying to do is to forecast unknown future time-series and then based on these predictions, to predict the target value (stock market). There are several ways to do so. The most intuitive one is that you can forecast each time series: apply a separate model to predict it; based on these results, to predict your target. An example can be this one (forecasting multivariate model): https://unit8co.github.io/darts/examples/16-hierarchical-reconciliation.html